# Consulta em Laravel usando tags SQL Like, where, and, or

Tags: laravel-5, where

Boa tarde galera estou tendo um problema pois preciso fazer a seguinte representação de consulta em laravel

```
SELECT * FROM imovels   AS i
INNER JOIN estados      AS e ON e.id = i.estado_id 
INNER JOIN cidades      AS c ON c.id = i.cidade_id
INNER JOIN bairros      AS b ON b.id = i.bairro_id
INNER JOIN tipos        AS t ON t.id = i.tipo_id
INNER JOIN finalidades          AS f ON f.id = i.finalidade_id


WHERE 
(i.finalidade_id = finalidadeId OR finalidadeId IS NULL) AND
(i.tipo_id = tipoId OR tipoId IS NULL) AND
(
i.titulo                        LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
i.descricao                     LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
i.valor                     LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
i.rua                   LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
i.codigo_interno                LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
e.nome                  LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
c.nome                  LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
b.nome                  LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
t.nome                  LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') OR
f.nome                  LIKE CONCAT('%',termo,'%') );
```

porem quando eu uso

```
DB::table('imovels')->orWhere('tipos.nome', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->q . '%')
```

eu consigo acessar  por ex. a propriedade de nome do tipo porem o array fica montado de forma diferente de quando eu faço com o

```
Imovel::with('imagens', 'estado', 'cidade', 'bairro', 'user', 'tipo', 'finalidade')
```

o array fica montado de maneira correta mas eu nao consigo comparar as propriedades das tabelas de relação.

Não sei se consegui ser claro. Mas agradeço qualquer tipo de ajuda.

Comment: Epah que confusão que vai para aí :P , vou tentar editar de maneira a que fique mais legível. Bem-vindo Davi

Comment: blz sem problemas

Comment: Talvez isto possa ajudá-lo a compreender o problema https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions